# List comprehension for finding all prime numbers from a range of numbers?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
[x for x in range(1,100) if all(x%y for y in range(2,x))]
```

Not able to understand how above code is returning correct results, Instead it should be

```
[x for x in range(1,100) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range(2,x))]
```

The reason is if all is `True` if only one of the condition is `True`.

Comment: `bool(x%y!=0)` is the same as `bool(x%y)`

Comment: `bool(0) = False`, `bool(1) = True`

Answer (score 4):

Non-zero integers are considered truthy in a boolean context, so the code snippets are equivalent.

Note that this algorithm incorrectly classifies `1` as a prime number.

Comment: @JoranBeasley  Yes. There is no question too simple, as long as it is clearly asked.

Comment: but i would assume there are about a million "dupes" around here ... with at least one being "canatonical" :P that said I +1 cause you are definately right :)